# The Ask Different Blog is looking for contributors

Tags: discussion, blog

A few days ago Stack Exchange set up a blog for Ask Different at http://apple.blogoverflow.com/, and we're looking for contributors! The topic set is the same as Ask Different - reviews, comparisons, and how-tos with [Apple hardware/software, etc](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). You can also write posts about Ask Different itself - how to ask a good question, how to use site features, and featuring excellent questions or answers from the site. And if you have a great idea of something to contribute that I haven't listed, just let us know and we'll let you know if it's something we can put up.

If you haven't already, I suggest looking at the [other Stack Exchange community blogs](http://blogoverflow.com/) to get a sense for what the blog will be like, and to get ideas for potential content to post.

The primary means of communication is our chat room, which is open to the public:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1408/ask-different-blog

If this sounds like something you'd be interested in contributing to, either selectively or on a regular schedule, or even if you're just curious and want to know more, please just drop a line either here or in the chat room and we'll get you hooked up with a contributor account on the blog and give you access to our Trello planning board.

Let's make it awesome!

Comment: Willing to get involved. How do I sign up?

Comment: @Moshe I added you to the blog as a contributor and to the Trello board. Welcome aboard!

Comment: Got it, thanks. :-D No clue how to edit the boards though...

Comment: @Moshe hmm, I don't see you as a member yet. I think you have to join (the link below the "View Board" button) to be able to edit

Answer (score 4):

I would love it if someone could write a "VOTE EARLY, VOTE OFTEN" style post.

Comment: Great idea! Would you be willing to write it? If not I'll add it to our list of potential topics, but if you want the topic it's yours

Comment: Yes!! Please write this!

Answer (score 4):

I'd be willing to review a couple of utility apps that make my "Mac-life" a lot easier, feel free to hook me up.

Comment: Consider yourself hooked up. Looking forward to reading your app reviews!

Comment: When I click the "Accept invite" button on Trello, the page just refreshed and shows me the button again...(tried a couple browsers, some problem)

Comment: Hm, haven't heard of that bug before. I could resend the invite, but I don't think that would do any good

Answer (score 2):

I'd be willing to write some posts about audio production and/or software development on the Mac. Could keep the audio production posts to GarageBand if people want to play along, or go in to Logic Studio...

Comment: That would be fantastic! Both Garageband and Logic would be great. And as someone that's had to do some audio editing for the podcast, I look forward to learning more about it. Software development is great too, so long as it focuses on the tools for the Mac and not so much on the actual programming.

Comment: I've added you as a contributor to the blog and sent an invite to our Trello board

Answer (score 2):

I would like to contribute by reviewing iOS apps, if you think that's in scope for the blog.

Comment: Absolutely! I've added you as a contributor to the blog and sent an invite for the Trello board. You can author the post in Wordpress, then submit it for publication when you're done. I look forward to reading your reviews!

Comment: @Kalamane, I saw that you have a draft up and I wanted to offer a couple of suggestions for consistency with some of our work so far, and then just a few other requests I'd like you to consider. Could you meet me in the [Ask Different Blog Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1408/ask-different-blog) some time? I'll be in there around standard business hours tomorrow, and of course, a *little bit* later too :).

Comment: @VxJasonxV I'm in the chat now.

Answer (score 0):

I can write, but not too often (school...) as long as I have a topic to write about. I don't have Lion, and I don't have an iOS device, so I'm somewhat limited in what I can write about.

Comment: This does sort of limit what you can write about, but you have been set up with an account on the blog so feel free to submit stuff for review. As far as topics, if nothing else, you could write about Ask Different itself - how to ask, the importance of voting, or even feature some great questions and/or answers that were posted recently

Answer (score 0):

I would like to review Mac OS X applications, but not too often.
My main focus will be developer tools, music apps and productivity apps.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you, I sort of dropped the ball around Thanksgiving and I'm in the process of picking it up again. I've created a contributor account on the blog and I've added you to the Trello board, such as it is. Feel free to write something up and ping me or Nathan when it's ready and we'll schedule it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be happy to contribute! I'm a iOS and Mac OS X developer and designer and I have written for Macworld, iPad and iPhone User, .net Magazine and Tuts+ and would love to write for an Apple blog! I'd love to write about iOS, Mac OS X and reviews of apps and look at Apple-oriented design!

Comment: Excellent! We'd love to have you contribute whatever you can - I've set you up with a contributor account in Wordpress and access to the Trello board we're using for coordination. Feel free to write up posts and ping me or Nathan when they're ready and we'll schedule them. Thanks!